# Enable audio functionality in your application while your iPhone Device is in Silent/Vibrate mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift4, avfoundation, swift5

I integrated a Video Player and faced a challenge while playing the audio or video i.e. the sound is muted in case your device is in SILENT MODE or VIBRATE MODE.

This is the default configuration settings for the IOS Device from the AVFoundation/AVKIt or Apple.

I searched on the [apple developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionCategoriesandModes/AudioSessionCategoriesandModes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH10) and different solutions on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) for enabling the device to the Ringing mode or Writing the code on your player view controller class.

But if we have numbers of class which is using the Audio Video functionality we have to write the same code again and again on every view controller. I think this is not a good practice at all.

So here I'm sharing the optimized way to achieve our desired result i.e. to unmute the audio, in case of the device whether it is in silent mode or vibrate mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are just simple steps to enable the audio functionality while your device is in silent or vibrate mode throughout the application, Just declaring at once.

Tested on iPhone 6, iPhone 8, iPhone XR and Simulators.

Step 1: Open the AppDelegate.swift Class file.

Step 2: Go to applicationDidBecomeActive function.

Step 3: Write the below code in applicationDidBecomeActive function

- In Swift 5:

  ```
  do {
           try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)
     } catch(let error) {
           print(error.localizedDescription)
     }
  ```
- In Swift 4 or lower:

  ```
     do {
           try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        } catch {
            // error handling or perform your desire function
        }
  ```
- In Objective C:

  ```
       [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
        setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
        error: nil];
  ```

Step 4: Compile and Run Your Project.

Hurray!!!

Happy To Help. Thanks.